# How to display simple mathematical formulas in a rich internet application

Tags: rich-internet-application

I have some mathematical formulas of the type

```
p = (l + m + n) / (i+j*2)
```

**Note:** This is just an example. The real equations are more complicated with several variables participating in the equations.

I want to display these formulas in a tree like structure in an interactive, rich web component.

Initially the screen should display

```
p = x/y
```

with p, x and y as boxes. The user can click on the box labeled x which will "unfold" the box to expand and display
`x = (l + m + n)` and so on.

Since this is a J2EE based application, I can use any RIA library compatible with J2EE.

Are there any 3rd party RIA libraries out there that can help me render these formulas?

Comment: Like LaTeX ( http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/ )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) has this down... check it out.

Comment: Nice--TeX into HTML, which would suggest an AJAX RIA framework like MO's.

Answer (score 0):

please see the below links:

http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/examples/Henrici.html

http://www.myphysicslab.com/web_math.html

http://amaya.software.informer.com/11.1/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML